# Convert PDF to Keynote - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, keynote

Is it possible to convert each page in a PDF into separate images and then add those images to separate slides in an Apple Keynote file all with Objective-C and on iOS? After that, if that was possible - I would then need to import that keynote file into Keynote, again, on iOS.

Comment: What about using 3rd party online services, send as an attachment and within few minutes you will get a mail with Keynote!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basic playing around with the core-graphics pdf api should get you the `UIImage`s for each page. For the Keynote part you might need to do some more digging.